# Randomly select observations within a group using dplyr/base function R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data such as this:

```
student.id <- c("142", "142", "567", "567", "347", "347", "567", "945")
flag.double <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0")
data <- data.frame(student.id, flag.double)
```

I want to group by student.id, filter down to students that have a `flag.double==1` and randomly select one student observation (from the two available occurrences of students). Then I want to merge this back into data.

This gives me the random observations I want:

```
flag <- data %>% 
  group_by(student.id) %>% 
  filter(flag.double==1) %>% 
  sample_n(flag.double, replace = T)
```

But now I need to merge this back into the original data frame so that I can I have a column flagging these observations that were chosen randomly.

Next, i just left joined this back into the data set.

```
data <- left_join(data, flag)
```

Everything WORKS well, but I hate how inefficient this all looks. I also don't like creating a new data frame just to join it back into the original one. Is there a more elegant dplyr, tidyr, plyr, pipe incorporated way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly that you want to select a single observation from the duplicated `student.id`s, you could generate an additional column indicating this sampling procedure:

```r
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)
data.frame(
    student.id = c("142", "142", "567","567","347","347", "567", "945"),
    flag.double = c("1","1","1", "1","1", "1","0", "0"),
    x = rnorm(8) # other data for expository purposes
  ) %>%
  group_by(student.id) %>%
  mutate(in_sample = ifelse(flag.double == 1, sample(0:1), NA))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   student.id [4]
#>   student.id flag.double       x in_sample
#>   <fct>      <fct>         <dbl>     <int>
#> 1 142        1           -0.560          1
#> 2 142        1           -0.230          0
#> 3 567        1            1.56           0
#> 4 567        1            0.0705         1
#> 5 347        1            0.129          0
#> 6 347        1            1.72           1
#> 7 567        0            0.461         NA
#> 8 945        0           -1.27          NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to take one and there's only two columns, then the following will work:

```
data %>% distinct(student.id,flag.double)
```

If you have another value column, and it's ok to choose the first:

```
data$row <- 1:nrow(data)
data[!duplicated(data[,c("student.id","flag.double")]),]
```

If you have another value column, and really need to sample:

```
data %>% group_by(student.id,flag.double) %>% sample_n(1)
```

Assuming your flag.double is correct, this works because those with 0 as flag.double, should be unique for id. Hence you can just group by both variables and then sample